# One web application provide both public and internal API, how to protect the internal API?

Tags: security, networking

A web application (war) provides two set of HTTP APIs, one is public to the clients on Internet, another is for internal and should not public to Internet. What is the best practice on network deployment to protect the internal API?

I know that a common way is to split the application into two deployables, put the frontend which serves public API in DMZ and put the backend which serves internal API in internal network. But for some reason I want to keep the application as one deployable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally we introduce a reverse proxy to hide the APIs inside internal network. Clients from Internet is only able to connect to the reverse proxy, the reverse proxy is configured to only forward requests to public API to the application.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things you could try here. For the private API I would really suggest cutting it off in to its own application that listens on a local only address. If you have to keep them together you could implement some sort of oauth setup that is required to use the internal API, making it so only users with valid oauth tokens can complete the API request to the restricted resources.

Comment: I agree with Daniel. Doesn't have to be OAuth, but use some authentication for the API (and HTTPS) and some access control list type stuff to limit access.

Comment: Authentication helps, but I'm seeking a way to prevent external client reaches the internal API. Because authentication credential might be leaked. The internal API is kind of integration interface for other system. Don't know if reverse proxy helps?